# Problem when converting JSON to XML using jq and xmlstarlet

Tags: json, xml, jq, xmlstarlet

I am trying to convert JSON file into XML using following command which used JQ and XMSTARTLET

```
jq -r 'def walk(f): . as $in | if type == "object" then reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key (.; .[$key] = ($in[$key] | walk(f))) | f else f end; walk(tostring) | gsub("&"; "&amp;")' input.json | xmlstarlet fo --omit-decl --indent-tab > output.xml
```

but it fails with following error

```
-:1.1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
{"@programName":"OWASP ZAP","@version":"D-2023-05-30","@generated":"Wed, 31 May
^
```

I verified my JSON file through online validator and it looks correct.

my input.json as follows

```json
{
    "@programName": "OWASP ZAP",
    "@version": "D-2023-05-30",
    "@generated": "Wed, 31 May 2023 16:25:43",
    "site":[ 
        {
            "@name": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
            "@host": "127.0.0.1",
            "@port": "8000",
            "@ssl": "false",
            "alerts": [ 
                {
                    "pluginid": "10038",
                    "alertRef": "10038-1",
                    "alert": "Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set",
                    "name": "Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set",
                    "riskcode": "2",
                    "confidence": "3",
                    "riskdesc": "Medium (High)",
                    "desc": "<p>Content Security Policy (CSP) is an added layer of security that helps to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, including Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and data injection attacks. These attacks are used for everything from data theft to site defacement or distribution of malware. CSP provides a set of standard HTTP headers that allow website owners to declare approved sources of content that browsers should be allowed to load on that page \u2014 covered types are JavaScript, CSS, HTML frames, fonts, images and embeddable objects such as Java applets, ActiveX, audio and video files.</p>",
                    "instances":[ 
                        {
                            "uri": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
                            "method": "GET",
                            "param": "",
                            "attack": "",
                            "evidence": "",
                            "otherinfo": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "uri": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/robots.txt",
                            "method": "GET",
                            "param": "",
                            "attack": "",
                            "evidence": "",
                            "otherinfo": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "uri": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml",
                            "method": "GET",
                            "param": "",
                            "attack": "",
                            "evidence": "",
                            "otherinfo": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "count": "3",
                    "solution": "<p>Ensure that your web server, application server, load balancer, etc. is configured to set the Content-Security-Policy header.</p>",
                    "otherinfo": "",
                    "reference": "<p>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy</p><p>https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.html</p><p>http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/</p><p>http://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/content-security-policy/csp-specification.dev.html</p><p>http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/</p><p>http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy</p><p>http://content-security-policy.com/</p>",
                    "cweid": "693",
                    "wascid": "15",
                    "sourceid": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I was not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here?

I actually wanted to convert the JSON into XML in following Junit format

```
<testsuites>
<testsuite tests="1" failures="1" name="127.0.0.1 - OWASP ZAP">
<properties>
<property name="type" value="OWASP ZAP"/>
</properties>
<testcase classname="Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set" failures="3" name="[Medium] - Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set" file="">
<failure message="Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set" type="failure">Description: Content Security Policy (CSP) is an added layer of security that helps to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, including Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and data injection attacks. These attacks are used for everything from data theft to site defacement or distribution of malware. CSP provides a set of standard HTTP headers that allow website owners to declare approved sources of content that browsers should be allowed to load on that page — covered types are JavaScript, CSS, HTML frames, fonts, images and embeddable objects such as Java applets, ActiveX, audio and video files. URIs Reported(3): - http://127.0.0.1:8000 - http://127.0.0.1:8000/robots.txt - http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml Solution: Ensure that your web server, application server, load balancer, etc. is configured to set the Content-Security-Policy header. OtherInfo: Reference: - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy - https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.html - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/ - http://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/content-security-policy/csp-specification.dev.html - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/ - http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy - http://content-security-policy.com/</failure>
</testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Number of alerts becomes the failure and tests count for  tag
"count": "3" becomes failure count for  tag
Urls are concatenated and shown under   tag after "URIs Reported(3):"

Moving further I found this question and some interesting answers. [Is it possible to convert from JSON or YAML to XML using jq/yq/xq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73038301/is-it-possible-to-convert-from-json-or-yaml-to-xml-using-jq-yq-xq)

I tried using the filter "json_to_xml.jq" mentioned over there with following command

jq -Rf json_to_xml.jq input.json > output.xml

which gave XML results in following format, but I need result in above mentioned desired format

```
<site name="http://127.0.0.1:8000" host="127.0.0.1" port="8000" ssl="false"><alerts><pluginid>10038</pluginid><alertRef>10038-1</alertRef><alert>Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set</alert><name>Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set</name><riskcode>2</riskcode><confidence>3</confidence><riskdesc>Medium (High)</riskdesc><desc>&lt;p&gt;Content Security Policy (CSP) is an added layer of security that helps to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, including Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and data injection attacks. These attacks are used for everything from data theft to site defacement or distribution of malware. CSP provides a set of standard HTTP headers that allow website owners to declare approved sources of content that browsers should be allowed to load on that page — covered types are JavaScript, CSS, HTML frames, fonts, images and embeddable objects such as Java applets, ActiveX, audio and video files.&lt;/p&gt;</desc><instances><uri>http://127.0.0.1:8000</uri><method>GET</method><param></param><attack></attack><evidence></evidence><otherinfo></otherinfo></instances><instances><uri>http://127.0.0.1:8000/robots.txt</uri><method>GET</method><param></param><attack></attack><evidence></evidence><otherinfo></otherinfo></instances><instances><uri>http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml</uri><method>GET</method><param></param><attack></attack><evidence></evidence><otherinfo></otherinfo></instances><count>3</count><solution>&lt;p&gt;Ensure that your web server, application server, load balancer, etc. is configured to set the Content-Security-Policy header.&lt;/p&gt;</solution><otherinfo></otherinfo><reference>&lt;p&gt;https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.html&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;http://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/content-security-policy/csp-specification.dev.html&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;http://content-security-policy.com/&lt;/p&gt;</reference><cweid>693</cweid><wascid>15</wascid><sourceid>1</sourceid></alerts></site>
```

Comment: Your `jq` command stringifies (using `tostring`) the JSON input object's fields (observable in the `.site` field), and attempts to replace `&` characters with `&amp;`, but at no point is it actually converting any part of the JSON input towards XML (except for the escaping of `&`), so `xmlstarlet` (rightly) complains about not receiving a well-formed XML ("Start tag expected, '<' not found"). -- Please explicate your desired XML output, and we can help you get there.

Comment: My desired output format is junit xml format, I am editing question and mentioning the desired format there

Comment: Thank you. Yet, the provenance of some details in the output are still unclear. Where do `tests="6"` and `failures="6"` come from, where `errors="0"` and `skipped="0"`, where `value="OWASP ZAP"`, etc.? (Did you expect `walk(tostring)` or `gsub("&"; "&amp;")` would accomplish all of this? If not, would you mind also showing what you have tried instead? Because this would automatically expose those missing links.)

Comment: Where's your conversion to XML happening? `xmlstarlet` can only process XML

Comment: @pmf Just made some changes in the source JSON and expected XML output

Answer (score 0):

Highly unclear about how and which elements relate to each other (especially on iterations, as your sample provides only one set, and falls short on many edge cases), but here's (at least for starters) one way how to transform your sample JSON structure into your sample XML using [xq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (which performs JSON <-> XML transformations, and uses jq under the hood):

```bash
echo '<x/>' | xq -xn --argfile in input.json '
  def print: strings /= "</p><p>" | map(ltrimstr("<p>") | rtrimstr("</p>")) | join(" - ");
  $in | {
    testsuites: {
      testsuite: {
        "@tests": (.site | length),
        "@failures": ([.site[].alerts[]] | length),
        "@name": "\([.site[]."@host"] | print) - \(."@programName")",
        properties: [{
          property: {
            "@name": "type",
            "@value": ."@programName"
          }
        }],
        "testcase": [.site[] | {
          "@classname": ([.alerts[].name] | print),
          "@failures": ([.alerts[].instances[]] | length),
          "@name": ([.alerts[] | "[\((.riskdesc / " ")[0])] - \(.name)"] | print),
          "@file": "",
          failure: [.alerts[] | {
            "@message": .alert,
            "@type": "failure",
            "#text": (
              "Description: \(.desc | print) " +
              "URIs Reported(\(.count)): - \([.instances[].uri] | print) " +
              "Solution: \(.solution | print) " +
              "OtherInfo: \(.otherinfo) " +
              "Reference: - \(.reference | print)"
            )
          }]
        }]
      }
    }
  }
'
```

```xml
<testsuites>
  <testsuite tests="1" failures="1" name="127.0.0.1 - OWASP ZAP">
    <properties>
      <property name="type" value="OWASP ZAP"></property>
    </properties>
    <testcase classname="Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set" failures="3" name="[Medium] - Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set" file="">
      <failure message="Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set" type="failure">Description: Content Security Policy (CSP) is an added layer of security that helps to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, including Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and data injection attacks. These attacks are used for everything from data theft to site defacement or distribution of malware. CSP provides a set of standard HTTP headers that allow website owners to declare approved sources of content that browsers should be allowed to load on that page — covered types are JavaScript, CSS, HTML frames, fonts, images and embeddable objects such as Java applets, ActiveX, audio and video files. URIs Reported(3): - http://127.0.0.1:8000 - http://127.0.0.1:8000/robots.txt - http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml Solution: Ensure that your web server, application server, load balancer, etc. is configured to set the Content-Security-Policy header. OtherInfo:  Reference: - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy - https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.html - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/ - http://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/content-security-policy/csp-specification.dev.html - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/ - http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy - http://content-security-policy.com/</failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```